# GridView центровать контент, с сохранением стиля и шаблона

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть GridView, когда выглядит вот так:

```
<ListView x:Name="Accounts" Margin="8" Grid.Column="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Storage.Accounts}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="По умолчанию">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton GroupName="DefaultAccount" Width="100"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
...
```

Выглядит это, с применением стиля MD вот так:

[image]

Необходимо сделать так, что-бы `RadioButton` был посередине столбца. `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` не работает.

Если погуглить, и применить этот код:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

То мы потеряем стиль, предоставляемый Material Design'ом.

Если же прописать `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}"`, то вся строка будет выглядеть как простой TextBox, в который написали название класса. Как сделать это правильно?

Comment: Вы с этим `Material Design'ом` себя в тупик загоняете. Научитесь работать для начала с чистым WPF, без каких либо фреймворков и когда вы это все освоите, облегчайте жизнь ими. Ну а по вопросу, [ищите тот стиль](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/ControlStyleList), что ставится `Material Design'ом` для этого элемента и наследуйтесь от него, а не от стандартного контрола.

Comment: Я умею работать с чистым WPF на достаточном уровне, и могу сделать уже большинство того, что мне нужно. Если вы про `BasedOn`, то я наследуюсь правильно, ибо MD ставил свой стиль по умолчанию. UDP - сейчас проверил, наследуюясь не от дефолтного, а прямо прописав нужный стиль ничего не изменилось, в смысле "*вся строка выглядит как простой TextBox, в который написали название класса*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignGridViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я узнал название стиля? Запускаем приложение, открываем окно Live Visual Tree, находим в дереве ListViewItem

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываем окно Live Property Explorer и смотрим значение свойства Style

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Удивительно, когда я делал то-же самое это не работало. Но всё равно спасибо.